# Dynamic curved value presenter

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: Mockup of the control]

In my WPF Application after a user input I am displaying a dashboard to present the outputs of the users data.

Now what I want to have is a control like above, where the blue fills the segment from left to right.
e.g. if the value returned is 100, the blue fills the whole segment and if it is 0 then there is no blue shown.

Its very easy to create this using normal rectangles but the curves are a challenge.
For reference with rectangles it works that, on a button click a value is created in the range of 0-100 and then I multiply this by the ratio of (rectangle width)/(Max value). then set the rectangles width equal to this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't you just use path and make another path curve user control and set the width of the inner path base on the value that was given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this [CodeProject arcticle](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28098/A-WPF-Pie-Chart-with-Data-Binding-Support) demonstrates how to do what you need.